# Как ограничить доступ в интернет отдельному классу ?

Tags: java, junit

При написании тестов на jUnit 4 столкнулся с необходимостью сымитировать потерю доступа в интернет для проверки устойчивости приложения. Есть какие-нибуть стандартные механизмы, которые это могут обеспечить ибо отключать WiFi при запуске тестов некошерно же.

Comment: конфигурирование firewall из командной строчки ? включаем / выключаем

Comment: коннект закрывай по таймауту рандомно, если хочешь автоматизировать имитацию

Comment: есть еще вариант разобратся как работает ваш роутер и удаленно отправлять ему команду ребут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все верно - ваш тест не должен зависеть от конфигурации и быть "полу" автоматическим. Скорее всего у вас сильно связанный код. Разделите на два метода - нормальное выполнение, и аварийное(скорее всего, метод с выбросом Exception). Тогда их можно будет проверить отдельно. Был бы код, объяснил бы с примером :)

Answer (score 2):

Вынесите кусок кода отвечающий за коннект в отдельный класс расширяющий стандартный функционал, например для сокетов:

```
public TestSocket extends Socket {
private Class myClass;
    public TestSocket(Class myClass) {
       super();
       this.myClass=myClass;
    }

    @Override
    public InpuStream getInputStream() {
       if(myClass.getName().indexOf("MyTestSuite") > 0) { //если это тестовый класс
           return new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0])); //возвращаем пустой поток
       return super.getInputStream();
       }
    }
}
```

Ну в общем схема как идея - дальше применительно к вашему коннекту можно развить и дальше.